# Any way to avoid using a macro for this C++ scoped logger?

Tags: c++, scope, c++20, diagnostics

I am refreshing some very old code in our diagnostic library to modern C++, and one piece of code remains that has always bothered me. It is a very common kind of scoped logging function that uses a macro to define the storage of logging data in an application-specific slot, simplified here as an int, with an optional version that takes a condition which is used to decide whether the timing should happen (for specific cases like first time through a loop, or when under extreme artificial external timing pressure, for example).

```
class ScopedTimer
{
   int mSlot;
   bool mCondition;
   Ticker mBeginTimer;
public:
  ScopedTimer( int slot, bool condition ) : 
      mSlot( slot ), 
      mCondition(condition)
   {
       if ( mCondition ) mBeginTimer = GetTimer(); 
   }

  ~ScopedTimer() 
  { 
       if (mCondition)
       {
           StoreInSlot( mSlot, GetTimer() - mBeginTimer ); 
       }
  }
};

#ifdef PROFILING_ENABLED
#define ST_NAME_CONCAT( x, y )      x ## _ ## y
#define ST_NAME_EVALUATOR( x, y ) ST_NAME_CONCAT( x, y )
#define ST_NAME( prefix ) ST_NAME_EVALUATOR( prefix, __LINE__ )
#define SCOPED_TIMER(slot) ScopedTimer ST_NAME(scopedTimer)( slot, condition )
#else
#define SCOPED_TIMER(slot) // goes away in release
#endif
```

and in use:

```
extern bool ConditionRequestsTiming();

void foo()
{
  SCOPED_TIMER( some_magic_slot_number, ConditionRequestsTiming() );

  ... other operations

}
```

Expands to

```
void foo()
{
  ScopedTimer scopedTimer12( some_magic_slot_number, ConditionRequestsTiming() );

  ... other operations

  // calling ~ScopedTimer() here, but only if ConditionRequestsTiming was true, storing time difference in the slot
}
```

And in release:

```
void foo()
{
  ... other operations
}
```

Which of course works as expected, giving a scoped timer for the method. It is very convenient, and less error prone, but it doesn't respect namespaces and that's always bothered me.

Any thoughts on a modern solution without too much complication, or should I just accept this pattern as okay for our diagnostic library?

Comment: Your macro doesn't use any pre-defined macros (`__LINE__`, etc) so what's wrong with `ScopedTimer a_name_that_is_unique_in_the_scope(some_magic_slot_number)`?  Also, any identifier with a double underscore is reserved to the implementation in C++, and your macro uses `__scopedTimer` so has undefined behaviour whenever it is used.

Comment: When doing this, always remember that the destructor may not throw. Else you'll have a problem. So I hope your "storing time difference in the slot" is safe. Anyhow, IMHO adding a macro which only function is to expand "SCOPED_TIMER" to "ScopedTimer __scopedTimer" is adding unnecessary complexity and making it more error prone. Finally: you shouldn't use double underscore identifiers, as they're used for the compiler internal structures....

Comment: The macro definition should probably not include the semicolon; that will be provided after the macro is invoked.  As it is, you'd end up with an extra null statement, which can be problematic and is (probably) not what's intended.

Comment: @JHBonarius the key for us is removing the code from release builds since it is part of the instrumentation library.

Answer (score 6):

Usually people use macros to append `__LINE__` to the declaration to allow for multiple declarations in one scope block.

Prior to C++20 this was impossible without macros. C++20 and later, with a little work, can use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

Jason Turner has a video on it in his C++ weekly video series [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAS85xmNDEc)

Comment: Casey, I forgot to include that code in our sample. I will look at std::source_location

Answer (score 2):

I was initially not sure to grasp the advantage of that macro, apart hiding the timer instance name (and cause possible conflicts).
But I think that the intent could be to have the possibility to do this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
  #define SCOPED_TIMER(slot) ScopedTimer __scopedTimer( slot );
#else
  #define SCOPED_TIMER(slot) ;
#endif
```

That would indeed save some keystrokes; otherwise, if the timing takes place also in release builds, I would simply use directly the macro definition; either way, I would get rid of the initial underscores in the object name (that are conventionally reserved for compiler implementers):

```
ScopedTimer scoped_timer( some_magic_slot_number );
```

Comment: The macro definitions should probably not include the semicolon; that will be provided after the macro is invoked.  As it is, you'd end up with a null statement (or two null statements) in a row, which can be problematic and is (probably) not what's intended.

Comment: This is exactly why we use a macro.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I initially misunderstood and instantly compiled multiple semicolons with gcc, clang and MSVC checking for any `NOP` or changes in the binary output! Well, I agree with you, I just followed the OP original (first version) `#define` with the semicolon...